# Separating an HTML Element String into Multiple Strings

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am webscraping using puppeteer and I am trying to extract the innerText of this h4 element.

```
<h4 class="loss">
(NA)
<br>
<span class="team-name">TEAMNAME</span>
<br>
<span class="win spoiler-wrap">0</span>
</h4>
```

I am able to get this element using:

```
const teamName = await matches.$eval('h4', (h4) => h4.innerHTML);
```

This will set teamName to:

```
(NA)<br><span class="team-name">TEAMNAME</span><br><span class="win spoiler-wrap">0</span>
```

I am trying to get only the inner text of each element.

I can get the (NA) using `const s = teamName.substr(0, teamName.indexOf('<'));`

But I cannot seem to figure out how to get "TEAMNAME" or "0" out of this string. I have thoughts of using regex, but I am not sure how I would accomplish this.

PS the inner text will not always be the same so I can't look for specific words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex, you can do it like this:

```
teamName.match(/<span class="team-name">(.*)<\/span>/)[1]
```

`match` returns an array, where the first element is the match of the whole regex, the second element is the match of the first regex group, the third element is the match of the second regex group (there is none in this case), etc.

The `/.../` marks a regex which matches the first biggest match it can find. `.` in a regex is any character. `*` specifies that any number of occurrences of the character is matched, including 0 occurences. `(...)` is a regex group, which is used by `match`. `\` is an escape character, because `/` is a special character to start and end a regex.

I very much recommend reading the Mozilla docs on [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and on [regexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for details. You will often find them useful.

However, in the case of puppeteer there probably also is a way of directly matching the selector `h4 span`, which would be more straightforward than using regexes. I don't know enough about puppeteer to tell you the exact way of doing that. :/

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you for your help.
However, I did notice that the last element  "<\/span>" needs to be "<\/span><br>" otherwise regex will use the last occurrence of span at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit more thinking, I was able to solve my issue.
Here is a solution:

```
const teamName = await matches.$eval('h4', (h4) => h4.innerHTML);
    const openSpanGT = teamName.indexOf('>', 20);
    const closeSpanLT = teamName.indexOf('<', openSpanGT);
    const teamTitle = teamName.substr(openSpanGT + 1, closeSpanLT - openSpanGT - 1);


    console.log(teamTitle);
```

This will output "TEAMNAME" no matter how long the string is.